# Connection to server socket on Android emulator

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-emulator, ip

I have simple server socket on my Android emulator. I start it on port 8080.
I want to connect to the server from my PC as follow:

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(X.X.X.X, 8080);
```

By what IP address should I use? I've tried "10.0.2.2" and "10.0.2.15" without success.

Comment: Have you tried the IP of your PC? Also let the firewall allows this port.

Comment: Yes, it does not work.

Comment: You want to connect from your PC to the server or from the emulator to the server?, in either case the destination address should be the IP of the server. In the server the firewall should allow port 8080 to get through. Port 8080 is used by various apps, make sure it's free.